# Hey so I've "bought" elementaryOS but no money got pulled from my card nor get a confrimation

Tags: elementary-project

Yup, so my concern is those two

1. What if I need to download ISO again? Will I have to repurchase it?
2. Will they take money or I've got it for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

**Q1 — What if I need to download ISO again? Will I have to repurchase it?**

You will not need to repurchase the ISO if you need to download it again (though I'm sure the Elementary developers would be thankful for some additional funding). Instead, what you can do is:

1. Click on the "$ Custom" box sandwiched between $30 and the "Purchase" button:
   [image: Pay What You Want]
2. Enter "0":
   [image: Goose Egg]
3. Press "Download elementary OS" to begin your download

**Q2 — Will they take money or I've got it for free?**

Payments are handled by Stripe and can sometimes have a slight delay, though this is rare. If you have not seen any payment come out of your credit card by this time tomorrow and you would *really like to* contribute to the project, consider returning to [the elementary OS site](https://elementary.io) and try again.

Thank you for supporting the eOS project